# eSocialBX: Erro de assinatura inválida

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, assinatura-digital, api

Estou tentando consumir o Webservice de Consulta aos Identificadores dos Eventos. Porém recebo esse retorno por parte da Receita:

```xml
<eSocial
xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/consulta/identificadores-eventos/retorno/v1_0_0">
<retornoConsultaIdentificadoresEvts>
    <status>
        <cdResposta>142</cdResposta>
        <descResposta>Assinatura do evento inválida. Padrão de assinatura não reconhecido.</descResposta>
    </status>
</retornoConsultaIdentificadoresEvts>
```

Esse é o xml que está enviando:

```xml
<s:Envelope
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador
        xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consulta/identificadores-eventos/v1_0_0"
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <consultaEventosEmpregador>
            <eSocial
                xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/consulta/identificadores-eventos/empregador/v1_0_0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
                    <ideEmpregador>
                        <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                        <nrInsc>00000000000100</nrInsc>
                    </ideEmpregador>
                    <consultaEvtsEmpregador>
                        <tpEvt>S-1250</tpEvt>
                        <perApur>2018-12</perApur>
                    </consultaEvtsEmpregador>
                </consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
                <Signature
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <SignedInfo>
                        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                        <Reference URI="">
                            <Transforms>
                                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                            </Transforms>
                            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                            <DigestValue>l6K5QTBqOn2R5OVwfyjAQn2tcY2KLt+/WwQleOZ+yCQ=</DigestValue>
                        </Reference>
                    </SignedInfo>
                    <SignatureValue>[...]</SignatureValue>
                    <KeyInfo>
                        <X509Data>
                            <X509Certificate>[...]</X509Certificate>
                        </X509Data>
                    </KeyInfo>
                </Signature>
            </eSocial>
        </consultaEventosEmpregador>
    </ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador>
</s:Body>
```

Este é o código, como é apenas para teste o certificado está fixo:

```
public static void ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador()
{
    ServicoConsultarIdentificadoresEventosClient client = new ServicoConsultarIdentificadoresEventosClient();
    eSocial esocial = new eSocial();
    esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts = new eSocialConsultaIdentificadoresEvts();
    esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.ideEmpregador = new TIdeEmpregador();
    esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.ideEmpregador.tpInsc = 1;
    esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.ideEmpregador.nrInsc = "00000000000100";
    esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.consultaEvtsEmpregador = new TConsultaEventosEmpregador();
    esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.consultaEvtsEmpregador.perApur = "2018-12";
    esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.consultaEvtsEmpregador.tpEvt = "S-1250";

    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    certificado = store.Certificates[7];

    var xml = Serialize(esocial);

    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificado;
    SignXmlDoc(xml, certificado);

    var retorno = client.ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador(xml.DocumentElement);
    client.Close();
}
```

E o código para assinatura, já tentei de várias formas, inclusive atualmente está idêntico ao dessa resposta: [ESocial - Erro ao assinar XML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277467/28505).

Usei ferramentas como **xsd.exe** e **svcutil.exe** para geração dos códigos.

Comment: O erro de assinatura foi corrigido, consegui utilizar a consulta de identificadores de eventos e a de download dos mesmos tanto na produção restrita quanto na produção

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sei dizer com exatidão qual foi a causa do erro mas consigo visualizar alguns problemas que podem ou não ser a causa desse erro, vou lista-los.

## 1. Namespace do elemento `eSocial` no XML

O elemento raiz `eSocial` deve conter o namespace específico do eSocial para aquele evento, mas não deve conter os atributos `xmlns:xsi` e `xmlns:xsd`, que normalmente são inseridos automaticamente pelo serializador. Veja o **item 3** dessa resposta: [EFD Reinf v1_04_00 - Como instanciar e preencher todas propriedades dos Eventos? - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348662/86952), que tem um exemplo de código para serializar o XML sem esses atributos.

## 2. Elementos SOAP no XML

No seu exemplo de XML há elementos do SOAP, como `<s:Envelope>` e `<s:Body>`, que não deveriam estar lá, porque o .NET se encarregará de pegar o seu XML e colocar em um envelope SOAP para enviar ao serviço. Além disso o XML possui o elemento `<ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador>` antes do `<eSocial>`, e ele também não deveria estar lá no XML. O elemento `<eSocial>` deve ser o raiz do documento.

## 3. Método errado

Você está usando o método errado para chamar o serviço! Pelo que entendi, você quer consultar o evento **S-1250** (*Aquisição de Produção Rural*), que faz parte dos Eventos Periódicos, então nesse caso você deveria usar o método `ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosTrabalhador`, ao invés do método `ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador`.

Veja a descrição dos métodos no [Manual de Orientação do Desenvolvedor eSocial versão 1.7](https://portal.esocial.gov.br/manuais/manualorientacaodesenvolvedoresocialv1-7.pdf), a partir da página 58:

> **5.6.2.1. Método `ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador`**
>   O método `consultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador` permite a consulta aos
>   identificadores dos eventos do empregador que não se enquadram nas categorias de eventos
>   de tabela ou eventos periódicos e não periódicos do trabalhador.
>
> **5.6.2.2. Método `ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosTabela`**
>   O método `consultarIdentificadoresEventosTabela` permite a consulta aos
>   identificadores de eventos de tabela do empregador.
>
> **5.6.2.3. Método `ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosTrabalhador`**
>   O método `consultarIdentificadoresEventosTrabalhador` permite a consulta aos
>   eventos periódicos e não periódicos do trabalhador vinculado ao empregador.

Pelo meu entendimento, o primeiro método `ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador`, que é o que você tentou usar, só seria usado para recuperar informações enviadas pelo evento S-1000, embora essa informação esteja bem confusa olhando a documentação e os esquemas XSD, já que nos exemplos do manual do método `ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosTabela` há um exemplo consultando justamente o evento S-1000, e no esquema do método `ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador` existe o elemento `tpEvt`, embora ele teoricamente só deveria aceitar o S-1000.

## 4. Bug do eSocial

Eu confesso que ainda não testei essa consulta, mas sei que ela ainda é bem problemática. Eu participo do fórum sobre eSocial da [**Fenainfo**](http://fenainfo.org.br/) (via e-mail) e até pouco tempo atrás as poucas pessoas que haviam tentado disseram que o serviço só funcionava no ambiente de Produção Restrita e no ambiente de Produção (oficial) se não me engano dava exatamente esse erro de assinatura inválida.

Se for esse o seu caso, aconselho que envie uma mensagem na área de [contato](https://portal.esocial.gov.br/servicos/producao-empresas/producao-empresas-1) do ambiente de Produção do eSocial, para relatar o problema.

---

## Exemplo de XML

Um exemplo de como o seu XML ficaria, **antes de assinar**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/consulta/identificadores-eventos/trabalhador/v1_0_0">
  <consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
    <ideEmpregador>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>12345678</nrInsc>
    </ideEmpregador>
    <consultaEvtsTrabalhador>
      <cpfTrab>12345678901</cpfTrab>
      <dtIni>2019-01-01T00:00:00</dtIni>
      <dtFim>2019-01-31T00:00:00</dtFim>
    </consultaEvtsTrabalhador>
  </consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
</eSocial>
```

E **depois de assinar:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/consulta/identificadores-eventos/trabalhador/v1_0_0">
  <consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
    <ideEmpregador>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>12345678</nrInsc>
    </ideEmpregador>
    <consultaEvtsTrabalhador>
      <cpfTrab>12345678901</cpfTrab>
      <dtIni>2019-01-01T00:00:00</dtIni>
      <dtFim>2019-01-31T00:00:00</dtFim>
    </consultaEvtsTrabalhador>
  </consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>[...]</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>[...]</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>[...]</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</eSocial>
```

Sim, o método correto `ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosTrabalhador` não tem um campo para especificar o tipo do evento que você quer consultar, o que me leva a crer que você receberá todos os eventos daquele CPF, no período especificado, e terá que identifica-los com o ID do evento que é retornado.

## Outras considerações

Também é bom lembrar das restrições do serviço, que estão listadas nas páginas 57 e 58 do mesmo manual:

> - As consultas não poderão ser realizadas entre os dias 1 a 7 de cada mês.
> - Cada empregador só poderá realizar uma consulta por vez, ou seja, não será permitido paralelismo neste Webservice.
> - Cada empregador poderá realizar no máximo 10 acessos por dia aos *Webservices* descritos nas seções *5.6 - Webservice de Consulta aos Identificadores dos Eventos* e *5.7 - Webservice de Solicitação de Download dos Eventos*, ou seja, a soma dos acessos aos Webservices mencionados acima não deverá ser superior a 10 por dia.
> - A consulta deverá ser realizada com data limite até uma hora a menos que a data atual.
> - Os retornos das consultas conterão os eventos recebidos até uma hora a menos que a data atual.

Também informações que obtive no fórum da Fenainfo é que esse **eSocialBX** que foi liberado (é o nome do produto que permite a consulta e download dos eventos previamente enviados ao eSocial) é um **eSocialBX Cirúrgico**, que foi liberado emergencialmente apenas para recuperação pontual de certos recibos (por isso ele ainda tem tantas restrições).

O serviço completo, que parece que se chamará **eSocialBX Data Lake**, ainda está sem previsão exata de liberação por parte do governo, e pelo que tudo indica será um serviço cobrado.

Comment: Agora que você mencionou percebi que o método está errado.

1. Tentei remover esses atributos manualmente, antes de assinar o xml, mas continuei com o mesmo problema.


2. Acredito que seja o .NET que está colocando meu xml no envelope, pois esse xml peguei no Fiddler. O evento que monto tem como tag raiz o eSocial. Sobre o elemento <ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador> não fui eu que coloquei mas vou tentar remover ele de alguma forma antes do envio

Comment: @Guilherme, hoje eu confirmei com o pessoal o fórum que continua dando esse erro de assinatura no ambiente de produção, então provavelmente a resposta para a sua pergunta é o item 4, bug do eSocial. Mas, de qualquer forma é bom arrumar as outras coisas para já deixar preparado. Você já tentou fazer o teste no ambiente de Produção Restrita? Dizem que lá está funcionando. Se você pegou esse XML pelo Fiddler então esquece esse ponto 2, realmente já foi o .NET que envelopou para você. Achei que esse era o XML que você estava usando para o envio!

Comment: menos mal que seja bug do eSocial, vou tentar enviar em produção restrita. Valeu sua resposta foi bastante útil.