# eSocialBX - targetNamespace inválido

Tags: python, api

Estamos tentando utilizar o eSocial BX para obter algumas informações dos eventos enviados.

Para a chamada `ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosTrabalhador` é enviado o seguinte XML (retirei a parte da assinatura):

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope
    xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header
        xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:Action>http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consulta/identificadores-eventos/v1_0_0/ServicoConsultarIdentificadoresEventos/ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosTrabalhador</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:73b1c7f5-ec50-465a-8e27-06f36cd55692</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:To>https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/dwlcirurgico/WsConsultarIdentificadoresEventos.svc</wsa:To>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <ns0:ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosTrabalhador xmlns:ns0="http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consulta/identificadores-eventos/v1_0_0">
            <ns0:consultaEventosTrabalhador xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns0:ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosTrabalhador">
                <ns0:consultaEventosTrabalhador>
                    <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/consulta/identificadores-eventos/trabalhador/v1_0_0">
                        <consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
                            <ideEmpregador>
                                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                                <nrInsc>12345678</nrInsc>
                            </ideEmpregador>
                            <consultaEvtsTrabalhador>
                                <cpfTrab>12345678900</cpfTrab>
                                <dtIni>2019-03-10T00:00:00</dtIni>
                                <dtFim>2019-04-10T23:59:59</dtFim>
                            </consultaEvtsTrabalhador>
                        </consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
                    </eSocial>
                </ns0:consultaEventosTrabalhador>
            </ns0:consultaEventosTrabalhador>
        </ns0:ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosTrabalhador>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

E o retorno é o seguinte:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/consulta/identificadores-eventos/retorno/v1_0_0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <retornoConsultaIdentificadoresEvts>
    <status>
      <cdResposta>417</cdResposta>
      <descResposta>Erro na estrutura da solicita&#231;&#227;o. targetNamespace inv&#225;lido.</descResposta>
    </status>
  </retornoConsultaIdentificadoresEvts>
</eSocial>
```

Alguém já passou  por isso? O mesmo acontece nas outras consultas deste serviço. Já tentamos contato com o suporte do eSocial, mas infelizmente não obtivemos uma resposta conclusiva.

Na busca aqui no StackOverflow encontrei apenas problemas relacionados com a assinatura [eSocialBX: Erro de assinatura inválida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356462/esocialbx-erro-de-assinatura-inv%C3%A1lida).

Comment: O erro estava na duplicação da tag `consultaEventosTrabalhador`. Corrigido isso, o sistema aceitou a requisição e retornou os IDs dos eventos.